# Issue while trying to import a .episerverdata file

Tags: episerver, episerver-6, episerver-mirroring-2.0

I am facing a strange issue when i am trying to import a .episerverdata file in my EpiServer site. It is giving the error Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Windows\TEMP\'.

Donot have any idea why it is giving like this.

Thanks and Regards
Utpal Maity

Answer (score 3):

If you rename the file .zip you should be able to open it and brows the content to see if there is something that looks strange. I.e search for the 'c:\Windows\TEMP' within the files.